# Plug angularjs directive into component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I currently have a generic list component and I want to add, depending on where I use it, different callbacks for adding/removing/updating items to that list.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
<div list-callback1>
    <generic-list
        add-callback="listCallback1.add()"
        update-callback="listCallback1.add(id, name)"
        delete-callback="listCallback1.delete(id)"></generic-list>
</div>
```

### My question:

Is there a way to decrease nesting? Because when I add the directive directly to my component I get a compile error.

Comment: It's not so clear what you are trying to achieve with the code, can you add a working fiddle? Besides, make sure you prompt the compile error angularjs threw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a different problem.

I had `scope: true` in my `list-callback1` directive.

After removing that, all works fine. Thanks for the help

Sorry I couldn't post more code, but I am restricted by my employer ;)